# Compute Coordinates From Arc Length In Snell's Law

Tags: integration, analysis

I want to build a raytracer for materials of continuous optical density.  I found (or actually someone on Reddit [found it for me](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/v7oc1y/continuous_optical_density/)) this [article](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Optics/Geometric_Optics_(Tatum)/01%3A_Reflection_and_Refraction/1.08%3A_Differential_Form_of_Snell%27s_Law), which is basically exactly what I needed.  Just a minor thing, it would be nice to have an inverse function of the arc length, so that I could plug the step size into some formula and receive the point at the end of the arc.  So my idea is, looking at $(1.8.5)$, to compute the arc length as something like $$\begin{align*}\int_\alpha^\psi\frac{dy}{\sin(\phi)}&=(y-k)\int_\alpha^\psi\frac{\tan(\phi)d\phi}{\sin(\phi)}\\&=\frac{k\cos(\alpha)}{\cos(\psi)}\int_\alpha^\psi \frac{\tan(\phi)d\phi}{\sin(\phi)}.\end{align*}$$ The last term can be further transformed by $$\int\frac{\tan(\phi)d\phi}{\sin(\phi)}=(\log(\cos+\sin)-\log(\cos-\sin))(\phi/2)$$ but I don't know if this helps to find the inverse to this function, I guess there is no easy way?

Comment: Sadly true. No easy way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  But are my calculations correct so far?  (I'm just worried that I made a mistake which makes it look impossible when it isn't.)

Comment: I don't know if your calculations are correct and it would take me more time than I have to check. They look reasonable.